# Unable to print the single data on separate page (laravel 8)

Tags: php, html, laravel, backend

I am trying to print a single user record. I have accessed all the records but I want to print one person's record on a separate page when I click print. I am unable to receive data in my controller.

```
@foreach($members as $member)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$member['id']}}</td>
        <td>{{$member['Name']}}</td>
        <td>{{$member['Date_Of_Birth']}}</td>
        <td>{{$member['Contact']}}</td>
        <td>{{$member['Email']}}</td>
        <td>{{$member['Emergency_contact']}}</td>
        <td>{{$member['Health_issues']}}</td>
        <td>{{$member['Address']}}</td>
        <td>{{$member['Registration_number']}}</td>
        <td>{{$member['degree']}}</td>
        <td>{{$member['Semester']}}</td>
        <td>{{$member['image']}}</td>
        <td><button id="printPageButton" ><a href="Member/{{$member->id}}"> Print</a></button></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Here is the controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\registration;

class MemberController extends Controller
{
    function show()
    {
        $data =  registration::all();
        //print_r($data);

        return view('list',['members'=>$data]);
    }
    function idcard(registration $members){
       
        print_r($members);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever checked the docs?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @PriyankMotivaras I am trying to print respective single person record when i click on print.

Comment: But you haven't written any code for that.